# In C program which find union and intersection of two input arrays, I have a problem in intersection part

Tags: c, arrays

In C program which find union and intersection of two input arrays, I have a problem in intersection part. The problem is when I print out the intersection array `I[u + z]`, the output is only one number repeated, without printing other intersections of the two arrays.**the part of code has the problem is at the end of the code**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, z, f ;
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    if(n <= 20) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter integer \n");
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d " ,a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter size of the 2nd array\n");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    int b[z];
    if(z <= 20 ){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < z; i++) {
            printf("Enter integer \n");
            scanf("%d", &b[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < z; i++) {
            printf("%d " ,b[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[i] == a[j]) {
                for(int l = j; l < n; l++)
                {
                    a[l] = a[l + 1];
                }
                n--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nArray1: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < z; t++) {
        for(int u = t + 1; u < z; u++) {
            if(b[t] == b[u]) {
                for(int l = u; l < z; l++)
                {
                    b[l] = b[l + 1];
                }
                z--;
                u--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nArray2: ");
    for(int e = 0; e < z; e++) {
        printf("%d ", b[e]);
    }
    int u[n + z] ; //union

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        u[i] = a[i];
    }
    for(int i = n ; i < n + z; i++) {
        u[i] = b[i - n];
    }
    for(int i = n ; i < n + z; i++) { //remove repeated values from union
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n + z; j++) {
            if(u[i] == u[j]) {
                for(int l = j; l < n + z; l++)
                {
                    u[l] = u[l + 1];
                }
                n + z--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n union is ");
    for(int i = n ; i < n + z; i++) {
        printf("%d ",u[i]);
    }

    // to get intersection  
    int I[n + z]; // to get intersection
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < z; j++) {
            if(a[i] == b[j]) {
                for(int k = 0; k < n + z; k++) {
                    I[k] = a[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n intersection is ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n + z; i++) {
        printf("%d ", I[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump all your code. If your problem is about intersection, edit out everything that is not necessary to demonstrate the problem. Show actual and expected behavior for a given input. In short, create a [mre]

Comment: It's best if you hard code the input arrays so you can skip the whole input code too.

Answer (score 0):

You should add only one number when you find equality, not for the whole array.

```
// to get intersection  
int I[n + z];
k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < z; j++)
        if(a[i] == b[j]) {
            I[k++] = a[i];
            break;
        }
printf("\n intersection is ");
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    printf("%d ", I[i]);
```

Comment: ok now if i entered two arrays a[1,2,3] and b[2,3,4] it only prints 2 ,while it should be 2 and 3

Comment: I tried it with a[1,2,3] and b[2,3,4] and got 2 and 3, check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a, b, A[100], B[100], I[100], i, j, k = 0, l; /* i have also taken
                                        intersection array. as I[100] */

 printf("pls enter the a and b respectively ..\n");
 scanf("%d%d", & a, & b);
 printf("pls enter the elements in A\n");
 for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
scanf("%d", & A[i]);
}
 printf("pls enter the elements in B\n");
 for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
 scanf("%d", & B[i]);
}

 // intersection calculation
 printf("intersection =");
 printf("{");
   for (i = 0, k = 0; i < a; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
     if (A[i] == B[j]) {

      printf("%d,", A[i]);
       I[k] = A[i];

    k++;
    }
  }
}
printf("}\n");
// lets find union

printf("union=");
printf("{");
 for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
 for (j = 0, l = 0; j < k; j++) {
   if (A[i] != I[j]) // this is A-B
  {

    l++;

    if (l == (k)) {
       printf("%d,", A[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

 for (i = 0, k = 0; i < a; i++) {
 for (j = 0; j < b; j++) {
  if (A[i] == B[j]) {

    printf("%d,", A[i]); // intersection
    I[k] = A[i];

    k++;
     }
   }
 }

 for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
 for (j = 0, l = 0; j < k; j++) {
  if (B[i] != I[j]) {

    l++;

    if (l == (k)) {
      printf("%d,", B[i]); //  this is B-A
    }
  }
 }
}
printf("}\n");

  // union calculation ended here

  printf("A-B = ");
  printf("{");
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  for (j = 0, l = 0; j < k; j++) // A-B calculation
 {
  if (A[i] != I[j]) {

    l++;

    if (l == (k)) {
      printf("%d,", A[i]);
    }
  }
 }
}
printf("}\n");

printf("B-A = "); // Calculates B-A
printf("{");

  for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
  for (j = 0, l = 0; j < k; j++) {
  if (B[i] != I[j]) {

    l++;

    if (l == (k)) {
      printf("%d,", B[i]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
printf("}\n");

return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain what changes you have made to the original code and what is the purpose of said fixes.